# "Gestures" plug not showing in switchboard

Tags: switchboard

Recently, I found out that the Gestures settings has gone from the elementary os settings app. I booted from the live usb to recheck that but found out that was still there in live usb but not in my main system. The multitouch gestures do work fine, only the gestures settings is not there. What could possibly be the cause, how to bring back the gestures settings plug? Any help would be highly appreciated
[image: See image for better understanding, no gestures plug is there!]